# change background color of current element

Tags: javascript, html

how can I change the background color of current element using plain javascript? for instance

```
<li onmouseover="this.backgroundColor:#000;">something</li>
```

This doesn't work, but you will get the idea what I want to do. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost there.

```
<li onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#000';">something</li>
```

Comment: Is it better to use hover css or javascript for this sort of things? I mean what is more elegant (better practice)

Comment: Are you just changing it one time? How important is cross browser? Do you have jquery?

Comment: It's very important that it should be cross-browser .. I used your javascript answer it works in IE8 most probably in IE7 as well .. and firefox of course, it renders almost anything .. I'll accept your answer. I won't use jquery cause I will not use a lot of its cool features, I just need "small" enhancements nothing fancy and no need to load additional nkb cause my background is pretty heavy ..

Comment: though css must be used indeed to solve the problem, i would not recommend inline javascript too. myLi.onmouseover=function(){} or something else is much better anyway. i don't know which browser excluding ie6 has not :hover support

Comment: I just tried IE8 , currently using it to view this website .. and it doesn't work and still plenty of people(the ones with illegal copy of windows) use IE6

Comment: Removed the link since it's now an Amazon redirect.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.style.backgroundColor= 'black';
```

Or if you can, better in simple CSS:

```
li:hover { background-color: black; }
```

Comment: Not all browsers fully suport the :hover psuedo-class

Comment: hmm I didn't know that hover works with li, I thougt its only used for a element

Comment: @Gandoalf, it does it more modern and standards compliant browsers.

Comment: Hmm.. it doesn't work in IE8 and most probably not in IE7 .. the hover thing

Comment: the hover pseudoclass does work in IE6+ on elements that already have that functionality. So pretty much just `<a>` tags.

Comment: first, ie6 is gonna die. second, since ie6 supports a:hover only, we can use "a:hover element" hack to simulate hover behavior with no javascript at all

Comment: I already have a tag inside <li> but I want the whole block to change the background

Comment: `li:hover` works on IE7 in Standards Mode (and you should definitely be using a Standards Mode DOCTYPE). If you really need IE6 to look ‘just right’ (personally for minor styling issues I don't always bother any more), then either put the hover on the `<a>` and style that with `display: block` to make it take up the whole width, or if that's not possible the old-school JS is the only solution left.

Comment: also i would like to say, i totally agree with bobince's last comment and two solutions he proposed (sure, the css solution is much better in the case). regarding to the javascript usage, i always divide javascript and markup to make the markup free of scripts and clear as it was shown in the post

Comment: Indeed. Inline attributes are good for demo code, but in real life binding from script is almost always the better route.

Answer (score 0):

CSS `hover` would probably be the most elegant solution, there is an IE6 fix for this:
[csshover.htc](http://snipplr.com/view/1912/internet-explorer-ie6-css-hover/)

But if it were me I would use jQuery, and it would provide you excellent cross-browser support.